# Execute function when the spacebar key is pressed

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```js
var drawGlob = function () {
  function keyPressed() {
    if (keyTyped === 32) {
      var size = (random(100, 150));
      fill(random(0, 255), 0, 0);
      ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, size, size);
      return false;
    }
  }
};
var draw = function () {
  noStroke();
  drawGlob();
};
```

After some testing, I discovered that the problem lies within:

```js
var draw = function () {
  noStroke();
  drawGlob();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where and how you are using it, more information would be useful. Anyway, in drawGlob you are declaring a function in a function, and where is it taking the variable keyTyped since it is not passed as arguments?

Are you referring to keyTyped the function? [maybe take a look to this example](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyTyped)

Maybe you meant keyCode [here another example](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed)

Edit: try this:

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === 32) {
    var size = (random(100, 150));
    fill(random(0, 255), 0, 0);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, size, size);
    return false;
  }
};
var draw = function() {
  noStroke();
};
```

So, when you press a Spacebar(32) it will trigger a random circle where the mouse is pointed.

Comment: i had already used the second example and it said keycode wasn't for spacebar. also i am using a website called hatch